# C++ nested templates structs

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming, template-specialization

So i have problem with code like this:

I have struct like this

```
template <int N>
struct Inner
{
    enum
    {
        val = 2*N
    };
};
```

And i want to achive sth like this:

```
int v = Outer<Inner<4>>::val;
int b = Outer<false>::val;
cout<< v <<endl;
cout<< b <<endl;
```

My goal is to created "`Outer`" struct which takes `bool` or `Inner<int N>`  and set `Outer::val` to `Inner::val` or `bool`
So i have created sth like this (not working):

```
template <bool B>
struct Outer
{
    enum
    {
        val = B
    };
};

template <Inner<int> I>
struct Outer
{
    enum
    {
        val = I::val
    };
};
```

Whats wrong with this and how to fix that?
(I have seen some similar questions, but still can't apply this to my problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems in your code.

First of all: you define **two** different `Outer` structs

```
template <bool B>
struct Outer
 { /* ... */ };

template <Inner<int> I>
struct Outer
 { /* ... */ };
```

And you can't.

If you want, you can declare an `Outer` struct and two **specializations**, but you have to decide what type of template argument `Outer` has to receive.

Because, looking at your desiderata,

```
int v = Outer<Inner<4>>::val;
int b = Outer<false>::val;
```

you want pass to it a type in one case (`Inner<4>`) and a value in the other case. And you can't.

You have to decide if `Outer` receive a type or a value. Before C++17, if receive a value, you have to decide the type of the value; starting from C++17, you can declare `Outer` as receiving a value of a generic type (`auto` as type of the value).

Problem: a value of `Inner<int>` can't be a template parameter (but see also the Michael Kenzel's answer, that show a possible C++20 solution based on template values arguments).

So the only solution I see (before C++20) is declare `Outer` as receiving a type

```
template <typename>
struct Outer;
```

Then you can define a `Outer` specialization for `Inner` types

```
template <int N>
struct Outer<Inner<N>>
 { enum { val = Inner<N>::val }; }; // or simply enum { val = N };
```

For `bool` values, you have to wrap they in a class; I suggest (starting from C++11) the use of the standard class `std::integral_constant` and the definition of the following `Outer` specialization

```
template <bool B>
struct Outer<std::integral_constant<bool, B>>
 { enum { val = B }; };
```

The use is as follows

```
int v = Outer<Inner<4>>::val;
int b = Outer<std::integral_constant<bool, false>>::val;

std::cout << v << std::endl;
std::cout << b << std::endl;
```

You can also use `std::false_type` defining `b`

```
int b = Outer<std::false_type>::val;
```

and, starting from C++17, also `std::bool_constant` (a shorthand for `std::integral_constant` for `bool` values)

```
int b = Outer<std::bool_constant<false>>::val;
```

Answer (score 2):

A template parameter can be either a type, a value (non-type), or a template [[temp.param]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.param). What you're trying to achieve would require your template `Outer` to have a parameter that can be either a type or a value. Unfortunately, this is not possible.

What you could do is wrap your bool value in a type:

```cpp
template <bool b>
struct InnerBoolean
{
    static constexpr bool val = b;
};
```

and then have one common definition for `Outer`

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct Outer
{
    enum
    {
        value = T::val
    };
};
```

and then use `Outer<Inner<4>>` and `Outer<InnerBoolean<False>>`.

Rather than write your own wrapper, if you rename `val` to `value`, you can use the wrappers that the standard library provides in [`std::bool_constant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) and `std::true_type` and `std::false_type`.

While up to C++17, a non-type template parameter cannot be of class type [[temp.param]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.param#4), C++20 will lift this restriction and allow template parameters of any [literal type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LiteralType). Thus, as long as `Inner` can be a literal type, you will be able to just pass a value of type `Inner` directly and use an auto template parameter:

```cpp
struct Inner
{
    int N;

    constexpr Inner(int N) : N(N) {}

    constexpr operator int() const { return 2*N; }
};

template <auto val>
struct Outer
{
    enum
    {
        value = val
    };
};

auto a = Outer<Inner(4)>::value;
auto c = Outer<false>::value;
```